# Accessing a string variable from one method to another

Tags: c#

```
    public static void Introduction{

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome");

        string MyName = "";

        Console.Write("What's your name ? : ");
            MyName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Hey {0},welcome to the quiz! ", MyName);

        Console.ReadLine();
     }
    //Quiz introduction

public static void FstQuestion(){

     //code

    if(...)
     {
     Console.WriteLine(" That's correct,{0} ! ",MyName);
     }

     else
        Console.WriteLine(" Keep trying,{0} ",MyName);
```

}

So i want to make a quiz in c#,however,i want the questions to be in different methods.As you can see, i want to save a variable with the user's name and use it whenever is needed.The problem is that i don't know how to call/use a string from another method.Any tip helps!Thank you!

Comment: define the variable as a  field in your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract `MyName` as a *static field* (in your current code `MyName` is a *local variable* and that's why is beyond of its *scope* in `FstQuestion()`):

```
 private static string MyName = "";

 ...

 public static void Introduction{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome");

    Console.Write("What's your name ? : ");

    MyName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Hey {0},welcome to the quiz! ", MyName);

    Console.ReadLine();
 }

 ...

 public static void FstQuestion() {
   //code

   if (...) {
     Console.WriteLine(" That's correct,{0} ! ",MyName);
   }
   else
     Console.WriteLine(" Keep trying,{0} ",MyName);
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this. Based on the technique of your example, you're programming procedural. *(which is a good start)*

You can return the name from the first method and pass it to the other.

So we start easy:

```
 public static void Main()
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome");

    // ask for the name and assign the return value to the local variable `myName`  
    string myName = AskName();

    Console.WriteLine("Hey {0},welcome to the quiz! ", myName);

    // enter the first question, pass the variable `myName` as parameter.
    FstQuestion(myName);
 }

 public static string AskName()  // <- notice the return type `string` instead of `void`
 {
    Console.Write("What's your name ? : ");
    string myName = Console.ReadLine();

    // this will return the value of `myName` to the caller.
    return myName;
 }

 //Quiz introduction

public static void FstQuestion(string myName)  // <-- notice the parameter
{
     //code

    if(...)
     {
     Console.WriteLine(" That's correct,{0} ! ",myName);
     }

     else
        Console.WriteLine(" Keep trying,{0} ",myName);
}
```

---

*Next lesson: classes and fields*

Answer (score 0):

Take look at "[Variable types and scopes](http://www.whatprogramming.com/csharp/variable-types-and-scope/)"

I recommend you to read a C# tutorial before programming something. This will help you with the basic stuff..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved in the following manners (some of them might appear sarcastic at first glance):

1. Send your variable as a parameter to your methods (standard, widely used, general-purpose solution).
2. Use a global variable, declared outside any method, thus accessible to all methods.
3. Save the variable value to disk file/system registry/Application setting. Read from there in every method.
4. Write to and read from Clipboard.
5. Use an online backup service to store it in the cloud. Use their API to fetch the value in every method.
6. Ask user's name in every method.

Answer (score 0):

In your Program.cs you'll have:

```
public class Program{

    public static void main(){
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

You'll want to add an instance variable to your class, so that for the duration that your class instance exists you can access it from inside your class(or from outside your class, but i'd wait with that) so:

```
    public class Program{

        private static string MyName;

        public static void main(){
            /*...*/
            MyName = Console.ReadLine()
        }

        public static void FstQuestion(){

        //code

        if(...)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" That's correct,{0} ! ", MyName);
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Keep trying,{0} ", MyName);
        }
    }
```